# Problems with connecting cassandra to elasticsearch node

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, elassandra

I just start using Elassandra, as it accomplishes the requirements for my project. I am following the documentation and trying to indexing
 the database as it shows:

http://elassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations.html#indexing

The problem is that the host ID name is different than the master_node

I have to change the configuration of `cassandra.yaml` to make sure that the cluster name is the same `cluster_name: 'elasticsearch'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I had it was a non capital letter in the datacenter naming of a command proposed for the tutorial.

`cqlsh>CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS twitter WITH replication={ 'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1':'1' };`

```
Datacenter: DC1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  416.17 KiB  256          ?       6a41ebba-c2da-43df-80fa-996accb4546a  rack1
```

so the problem was solved changing `'dc1':'1'` for `'DC1':'1'`